# Python input() gives is not defined

Tags: python

I got a python code from some book like below, but it runs abnormally.

```
# name.py

name = input('What is your first name? ')
print('Hello ' + name.capitalize() + '!')
```

The result is:

```
$ python name.py
What is your first name? jack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "name.py", line 3, in <module>
    name = input('What is your first name? ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'jack' is not defined
```

What is wrong with it?
Thanks!

Comment: It is perfectly running at my end. Which python version you are using?

Comment: I forgot to mention the Python version. The book uses python 3 while I use python 2.7, this may cause the problem. @AmitSharma

Comment: Yes!! that is why you are facing the problem. `raw_input()` does not exist in Python 3.x, while `input()` does. You can just assume that old `raw_input()` has been renamed to `input()`. They both are same.

Answer (score 7):

Because it's how `input` works. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input You have to use `raw_input` instead.

Answer (score 6):

That book is written for Python 3. The old Python 2 `input()` function works differently to the Python 3 `input()`. As mentioned in the docs linked by troolee, Python 2 `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`, which is convenient, but can also be [dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) since any input string is evaluated.

So to run Python 3 code examples on Python 2 you need to replace `input()` calls with `raw_input()`.

There are other differences that will cause Python 3 code to not work (or at least work differently) on Python 2. In particular, the old `print` statement no longer exists in Python 3, it's been replaced by a `print()` function. Some Python 3 `print()` function calls will work on Python 2, but some won't.